# Expectation of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

I am looking at a math problem that is asking me to determine $\mathbb{E}[e^{X}]$ given that $X$ is a random variable, and the probability density function of $X$ is given by

$$ f(x) =\begin{cases} 
      1 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise.} 
   \end{cases}
$$

The solution from the answer key is below:

Let $Y = e^{X}.$ Then we wish to determine $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. But first, we need to find the probability density function $f_{y}$ of $Y$. To do that, we begin with the probability cumulative distribution function $F_{Y}$ of $Y$:

$$
\begin{align}
F_{Y} = P\{Y \leq x\} \\
= P\{e^{X} \leq x\} \\
= P\{X \leq \log(x)\} \\
= \int_{0}^{\log(x)} f(y) \mathop{dy} \\
= \log(x).
\end{align}
$$

Differentiating, we obtain $f_{Y} = \dfrac{1}{x}$. Then we have $$\mathbb{E}[e^{X}] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{Y}(x) \mathop{dx} $$

$$= e - 1.$$

**My question:**

I don't understand why the integrand is $f(y)$ and not $f(x)$ when we're determining $F_{Y}$. I thought $P\{X \leq \log(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\log(x)} f_{X}(x)$, where $f_{X}$ is the probability density function of $X$.

Comment: Limit of the integral depends on $x$, so it is better to use $y$ as a dummy variable instead of $x$ itself to avoid confusion. And when one writes $f(y)$, it means the exact same pdf of $X$ as defined in the beginning.

Comment: Instead of finding the density of $Y$, it is simpler to say $E(e^X)=\int_0^1 e^x f(x)\,dx$ using the [*Law of the unconscious statistician*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. I did not know about that law. It looks much faster that way. Thank you!

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I have never heard that theorem given a name.  About as good as any, I guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is confusing you by using $y$ for two different things.  In the integral, $y$ is just a dummy variable.  They could just as easily have used $t$ instead of $y$.